# Django ImportError: Module "social_core.backends.google" does not define a "GoogleOpenId" attribute/class

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-rest-auth, django-oauth, django-openid-auth

I've cloned my working Django app into a Debian based Linux distribution, I've installed all dependencies, but when trying to login with email and password or with Google account it throws me the following error:

```
ImportError: Module "social_core.backends.google" does not define a "GoogleOpenId" attribute/class
```

I have the following dependencies for authentication:

```
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
google-auth==1.27.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
social-auth-app-django==3.1.0
social-auth-core==4.0.3
```

It was working well in Ubuntu and MacOs, the problem appeared when cloning to this Debian Based Distro. Google says nothing about this error and I don't know where to start searching, the only thing I've found is that we are using it as an Authentication backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId', 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment below, which explains python-social-auth deprecation, I've solved the issue by downgrading `social-auth-core` package from version `4.0.3` to `3.3.3`:

Answer (score 0):

GoogleOpenID is no longer in use, so it was removed from python-social-auth. But they must have forgotten to update the docs.

https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/472

https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-docs/issues/65