# How do I fix 'Module social_core.backends.google does not define a GoogleOpenId attribute/class' error in Django login?

Tags: django

I pulled the old Django project but when I log in, I got the following error.

Module "social_core.backends.google" does not define a "GoogleOpenId" attribute/class

I searched for this error but I can't find any solution.

I tried this but not working.

[Django ImportError: Module "social_core.backends.google" does not define a "GoogleOpenId" attribute/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327139/django-importerror-module-social-core-backends-google-does-not-define-a-goog)